# Buffer clearing - Output not as expected

Tags: c, file-io, buffer

C89 C: I've found plenty on getchars and clearerr and but I'm still a little confused. I'm hoping someone can point out we're I'm going wrong.

The code below parses a text file and prints out line per line with the LINEMAX defined as 30. The **myFile** input file is legit as I get *an* answer, just not the one I expect.

```
void printFile(const char* myFile)
{
    /* declare variables */
    char lineString[LINEMAX];
    FILE* lineReader;
    int lineCount;

    /* initialise  */
    lineReader = fopen(myFile, "r");
    lineCount = 1;

    /* parse the text */
    while(fgets(lineString, LINEMAX, lineReader))
    {
        /* check if last character is '\n' */
        if (lineString[strlen(lineString) - 1] != '\n')
        {
            /* check if final line (may not have '\n' character) */
            if(!feof(lineReader))
            {
                printf("ERROR: >30 characters. Buffer overload\n");
                bufferControl(lineReader);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d: %s", lineCount++, lineString);
        } 
    }
}

void bufferControl(FILE* lineReader)
{
    int ch;

    /* parse all characters until it runs out of leftover input */
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
    clearerr(lineReader);
}
```

Now, my input file is simple text file:

```
Jack Shephard Surgeon
Kate Austen Criminal
Joe Smith Antidisestablishmentarialist
Hurley Reyes Philanthropist
Sun-Hwa Kwon Executive
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
1: Jack Shephard Surgeon
2: Kate Austen Criminal
ERROR: >30 characters. Buffer overload
3: Hurley Reyes Philanthropist
4: Sun-Hwa Kwon Executive
```

But I get:

```
1: Jack Shephard Surgeon
2: Kate Austen Criminal
ERROR: >30 characters. Buffer overload
3: tarialist
4: Hurley Reyes Philanthropist
5: Sun-Hwa Kwon Executive
```

... where at the third line after the *'Buffer overload'* I have to press Return to continue (which is probably a clue but I'm not getting it, sorry). My understanding tells me that the bufferControl should remove the *'tarialist'* characters but apparently not. Can someone please explain to me what I am misunderstanding. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, for the first part. But shouldn't the bufferControl function drop the overloaded characters so it doesn't bleed into the next run? It's the solution I've seen in most places or am I not applying this correctly?

Comment: OT (Just curious) Are you sure you are really using a C89 compiler?

Comment: We have to use the flag compiler '-ansi' for uni to encourage us to write more portable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have this

```
/* parse all characters until it runs out of leftover input */
```

become true, you want to replace

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

by

```
while ((ch = fgetc(lineReader)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

From [man `getchar()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html):

> **getchar**() is equivalent to **getc**(*stdin*).

Comment: Ha, that works! Ah man, I wasted so many hours on this. I think I got a red herring from uni notes... Cool -  it's got my vote but before I close, just a quick question: is the general approach here the way to go about doing what I'm trying to achieve or is there a more 'proper' way?

Comment: @thatsHeavyDoc: reading document (aka man-pages) often helps a lot! ;-)

Comment: @thatsHeavyDoc: You did not explicitly told us what you were "*trying to achieve*".

Comment: @thatsHeavyDoc: What the code misses is to check if `fgets()` failed. To do so you want to put a call to `ferror()` right after the `while`-loop. Also the code does not check if `fopen()` failed. Not nice.

Comment: Just trying to achieve handling overflow while applying slight variations to working Uni examples. Those examples were manual input, not a file sourced stream, so maybe that's different? I did check out the manual but I guess interpreting it is another story: getchar == getc(stdin) which "acts essentially identically to fgetc() but is a macro that expands in-line". Que?
 I'm not grasping the fundamental differences here - or why we were told to use clearerr() which "clears the EOF and error indicators for stream pointed to by stream". All good. I've got some direction now so much appreciated.

Comment: Also, error handling notes taken on board too. Thanks!